# Slick Carousel how to get current slide as a dom or jquery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

Using [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), I have a simple carousel along the lines of:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="image"><img src="http://path/to/image.jpg" data-caption="Caption 1"></div>
  <div class="image"><img src="http://path/to/image2.jpg" data-caption="Caption 2"></div>
  <div class="image"><img src="http://path/to/image3.jpg" data-caption="Caption 3"></div>
</div>
```

I am initializing the carousel with an `onAfterChange` function to try to update the caption in another div but am a bit confused about how to get this div as a dom or jquery object?

```
$('.carousel').slick({
  lazyLoad: 'progressive',
  onAfterChange: function(slider,index){
    console.log(???);
  }
});
```

Where `slider` returns the carousel object and `index` returns the current slide.

How could I get the `data-caption` value out of this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Arg, apologies, I found a solution on a github issue titled [Accessing Current Slide Attributes in onAfterChange #411](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/411).

`slider` refers to the carousel, so one would access the slider so:

`$(slider)` and can access the particular slide with `$(slider.$slides.get(index))`

So in reference to my question above, it would be simply:

```
$(slider.$slides.get(index)).data('caption');
```

Comment: You'll probably want to modify this, as `$(slider.$slides.get(index))` will return the DOM node of the Slick slide wrapper. Using current doc variables names (for `afterChange` event), I came to this : `jQuery(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide)).find('.your-slide-selector').data('your-data-attr')`.

Answer (score 16):

```
$('.SlickContainer').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var CurrentSlideDom=$(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide));
    var NextSlideDom=$(slick.$slides.get(nextSlide));
});
```

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
$('.carousel').on('afterChange', function() {
    var dataId = $('.slick-current').attr("data-slick-index");    
    console.log(dataId);
});
```

Comment: still works great in 2022

Answer (score 1):

**Before Change**

```
jQuery('.pt-slick-carousel__slides').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
        console.log(jQuery('.pt-slick-carousel__slides .slick-active').attr('data-slick-index'));
        console.log(jQuery('.pt-slick-carousel__slides .slick-active').attr('id'));
});
```

**AfterChange**

```
jQuery('.pt-slick-carousel__slides').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
        console.log(jQuery('.pt-slick-carousel__slides .slick-active').attr('data-slick-index'));
        console.log(jQuery('.pt-slick-carousel__slides .slick-active').attr('id'));
});
```